# Connecting to Azure SQL Database via Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, azure-rm-template

I was trying to get powershell connect to Azure SQL Database from local. I tried the following snippet

```
$params = @{
  'Database' = 'dbsitenamehere'
  'ServerInstance' =  'instancename.database.windows.net'
  'Username' = 'abcites'
  'Password' = 'atbasIcpr0d'
  'OutputSqlErrors' = $true
  'Query' = 'SELECT * FROM Users'
 }
 Invoke-Sqlcmd  @params
```

But I was getting this warning:

> WARNING: Could not obtain SQL Server Service information. An attempt to connect to WMI on 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Types.ps1xml' failed with the following error: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

I think, resolved the above with the solution by turning on RPC Locator service from component services link manually as shared by Hodentek @ http://hodentekmsss.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-overcome-error-while-importing.html >> "How to overcome error while importing the SQLPS module into Powershell?"

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> Import-Module “sqlps” -DisableNameChecking
PS SQLSERVER:\> cd SQL
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL> dir
  MachineName                     
  -----------                     
  PC181578                        

PS SQLSERVER:\SQL> cd LocalHost
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\LocalHost> dir
```

But I get the following error and stuck. I am missing something silly I guess. . Exhausted, :(

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Invalid object name 'Users'.
At line:17 char:3
+   Invoke-Sqlcmd  @params
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

Request some suggestions that could get me going. I feel missing missing something in my approach to get connected.

Thanks

H Bala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RPC Locator service start was definitely correct step.It got the warning and local lookup corrected.

But the reason that I got the "Invalid object error" was because import was completing yet not creating all the schema as defined.

**Close Observations revealed the following:**

**1.  Get-AzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus returns no status.**

```
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -RequestId $ImportRequest.RequestGuid            
  -ServerName $deployParameters.Item('sqlserverName') 
  -Username $credential.UserName
```

2. Attempted programmatically as below to know the **progress, *reveals it gets stuck at 5%*** and then suddenly flashes *complete*.

   ```
       $ImportRequest = Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport -SqlConnectionContext $SqlCtx -StorageContainer $Container -DatabaseName $deployParameters.Item('databaseName') -BlobName $BlobName

                       # Check the status of the import
                   Do
                   {
                       $importStatus = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -Request $importRequest

                       # Check if import failed
                       if($importStatus.Status -eq "Failed")
                       {
                           Write-Output -Message $importStatus.ErrorMessage
                           $importDone = 1;
                       }

                       # Check if import is completed
                       if($importStatus.Status -eq "Completed")
                       {
                           Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Restore database complete"
                           $importDone = 1;
                       }

                       # If not failed or completed, return the status of the current import
                       if(($importStatus.Status -ne "Completed" -or $importStatus.Status -ne "Failed") -and $importDone -ne 1)
                       {
                           Write-Output "$(Get-Date -f $timeStampFormat) - Import status: $($importStatus.Status)"
                       }

                       # Added a sleep so that the Write-Output doesn't get flooded
                       Start-Sleep -s 3
                   }While($importDone -ne 1)
   ```
3. Attempted directly **on PS prompt gets me the import as completed** though on SSMS, i can see **only 30% of tables created**!!

   ```
     PS SQLSERVER:\> Get-AzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -RequestId  
     $ImportRequest.RequestGuid -ServerName   
     $deployParameters.Item('sqlserverName') -Username $credential.UserName
     cmdlet Get-AzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus at command pipeline   position 1
     Supply values for the following parameters:
     (Type !? for Help.)
     Password: ABCEfg1pr0
   ```

> BlobUri          : https://ABC.blob.core.windows.net/kind-snapshot/kind-snapshot.bacpac
>
> DatabaseName     : Pilotdbtrialrun
>
> ErrorMessage     :
>
> LastModifiedTime : 6/3/2016 2:29:29 PM
>
> QueuedTime       : 6/3/2016 2:27:42 PM
>
> RequestId        : 0f76af7b-7452-4cd4-a7a8-d6XXX4dc5923
>
> RequestType      : Import
>
> ServerName       : pilotsrvrtrialrun.database.windows.net
>
> Status           : Completed
>
> ExtensionData    :

**4. Import via portal for same backpac creates full database tables properly.**

Comment: Any suggestion on why bacpac import is behaving differently when done through Powershell and Portal?